# How to use Concatenate layers in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

My code like this:

```
balabala...
conv_model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())

input2 = keras.models.Sequential()
input2.add(keras.layers.Activation('linear', input_shape=(1,)))

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Merge([conv_model, input2], mode='concat'))
balabala.....
```

When I run this code, it says:

```
UserWarning: The `Merge` layer is deprecated and will be removed after 
08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, 
`concatenate`, etc.
```

I have tried to use 'keras.layers.Concatenate' in many ways like:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Concatenate([conv_model, angle]))
```

But it says:

```
The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or 
`batch_input_shape` argument
```

Is anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

Sequential models are not supposed to work with branches.

You need a functional API model.

```
input2 = Input((1,))
out2 = Activation('linear')(input2) 

concatenated = Concatenate(axis=chooseOne)([conv_model.output,out2])

model = Model([conv_model.input,input2], concatenated)
```

PS: the layer `Activation('linear')` does absolutely nothing in any model.

Comment: Thanks, this model comes from a forum. It seems this model has many problems.

Comment: And, this code runs fine. I just want to know how to change Merge to Concatenate.